# The cost savings "are" or "is" 50%?

Tags: plural-forms, singular-vs-plural, singular

I wonder if I should use **are** or **is** in the following sentence:

> The cost savings ____ 50%?

Or should I just say the cost savings percentage is 50%.
Thanks

Comment: Is it from a test? Do you need to choose between two options, or are you free to fill in any word you would find appropriate?

Comment: It's interesting why **cost savings is** is used. Could it be a tricky part of a larger phrase in some instances, like "The plan that you say will result in **cost savings is** a recipe for disaster". This would disqualify some of the ngram results.

Comment: @CopperKettle *Cost savings is* comes naturally to me. Perhaps this is a BrE/AmE distinction. There is only one set of savings, regardless of how many units of money it represents.

Comment: @choster - I've run an ngram search for "*the cost savings is*", and it returned zero results...

Comment: On closer examination, my NGram was misleading, and I wondered if I had just had a brain fart. But no, *the savings is* is definitely in use: *[The savings is the difference](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2010/11/13/weekinreview/deficits-graphic.html)*, *[The savings is equivalent to](http://www.energy.ca.gov/2015publications/CEC-400-2015-041/CEC-400-2015-041-FS.pdf)*, *[The savings is immediate](http://www.economist.com/blogs/gulliver/2014/04/fuel-prices)*, *[The savings is not always substantial](http://www.dau.mil/pubscats/pubscats/AR%20Journal/arq97/washingts.pdf)*, etc.

Comment: There is a cost savings of 50%. Or: There is a 50% cost savings. Please note: there is no BrE/AmE issue here **at all**. The search term would be: a cost savings of [some amount].

Answer (score 1):

I would say definitely *don't* rephrase to include the word "percentage". Bear in mind that "50%" is pronounced "fifty percent" - saying *the saving percentage is fifty percent* would sound incredibly awkward to any native speaker, and discarding the actual word "percent" wouldn't be much better (nor would it match the written form).

Idiomatically, the usual form is ***the cost savings are fifty percent***, but there's nothing at all wrong with ***the cost saving is fifty percent*** - it's just [less common, particularly in more recent decades.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20cost%20saving%20is%2Cthe%20cost%20savings%20are&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20cost%20saving%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20cost%20savings%20are%3B%2Cc0)

Mixing a plural subject with a singular verb is rarely acceptable in English; this isn't one of the rare exceptions. As to whether the *saving(s)* should be singular or plural, I would say that if you're definitely referring to the cost of *one single thing* you can't use the plural form. In (almost?) all other contexts you can use either singular or plural.

I say "almost" because I can't think of a context where you can't use the singular form (it's probably *always* possible to conceptualize all costs or savings as one cost or one saving), but it's at least *feasible* someone can think of a context where only the plural form works.

Comment: Thanks. I checked but saving vs savings and majority will say people rarely use saving. Seems like there is no clear answer... too ab i have to use this phrase a lot as my work is requires me to

Comment: @hj630: Per my final paragraph, unless anyone can think of a context *where you can't use the singular form* (I can't), the clear answer for anyone who's not sure is ***Always use singular "saving"***. It's not really important that this happens to be the less common form, if the net result is  that no-one would ever think you've made a "mistake".

Answer (score 1):

“Are” is always used with plural words—savings are.  “Is” is always used with singular words—saving is.  In this case, I believe the trouble you’re having is not with are vs is but rather the word savings.  The correct sentence would be: The cost saving (no s)is 50%.

Answer (score -1):

"Is" is the correct answer. What you are referring to is a singular percentage of a singular cost. What the number is before the percentage is irrelevant. It is a singular percent so the cost savings IS 50%.

A counter example would be if there were multiple costs.

"The costs(plural) savings are 50%"

Answer (score -1):

@discodane is right. Saving is only used when it refer to one instance of reducing something. Remember when you put "ing" at the end of a verb, you change the verb into a noun. That's the only case where saving is used. See the following example:

> You can enjoy a year's membership for just $28 – a saving of $7 off
>   the regular rate.

In the case above, you can change saving to reduction or reducing.

As for the case where the word **savings** is used, bear in mind savings is a **word/term**, instead of the plural form of saving.  So I believe the answer to your question should be

> The cost savings **is** 50%.